# How to create an Android app which can run on API 19 (4.4 Kitkat) but still has the look of API 21 (5.0 Lollipop)?

Tags: android, layout, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm building an app but I would love to upgrade it to the Android Lollipop design. I use Android Studio to develop my application and I set my minimum SKD to API 21 (Lollipop) and I want it to run on Kitkat and Lollipop, so now I got the Lollipop interface and want to run it on Kitkat but ofcourse this isn't possible because the minimum is Lollipop. And as I expected it didn't ran on Kitkat. So I changed the minimum SKD to 19 in build.gradle and the target SKD I let as it was (SKD 21) so now Kitkat could run the app but the full layout is Kitkat style , not Lollipop. Even tho I made the app as Lollipop design and Android Studio previewed it as Lollipop interface. I hope somebody could help me get the Lollipop interface on Kitkat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search for old threads where the same problem was discussed of `runs on Gingerbread but looks good on Ice Cream Sandwich`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not strictly possible to get "the Lollipop interface on Kitkat". You are welcome to [use the `appcompat-v7` backport](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), which will give you:

- an action bar styled according to Material Design and therefore reminiscent, though not identical, to the native Android 5.0+ action bar
- tints applied to certain widgets
- a `Switch` backport that looks like the Android 5.0 version of `Switch`
- a `Toolbar` backport

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Material Design, on Pre Lollipop devices by using android support library `appcompat_v7 rev21`and then setting the theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` as `@android:style/Theme.Material (dark version)` **OR** `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light (light version)` **OR** `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`

**Below are the official links for doing the same :**
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7

Hope this Helps!